# Given a row name (m) find column names (n) when (m,n)=x in a MySQL database as part of a PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am building a website as a diagnostic aid for neurological conditions. It is coded in html and communicates with a MySQL database via PHP. The primary table which feeds information to the website is structured as follows:
Image showing table structure with rows representing Neurological Conditions and columns providing information on symptoms associated with these conditions

[image]

The table above can be reproduced using the following MySQL code:

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
    `Condition` VARCHAR(22) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `Diarrhoea` INT,
    `Headache` INT,
    `Hyporeflexia` INT,
    `Hypoaesthesia_Spinothalamic` INT
);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
    ('Abetalipoproteinaemia',1,NULL,1,NULL),
    ('Caffeine toxicity',1,1,NULL,NULL),
    ('Vitamin B12 deficiency',NULL,NULL,1,2);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

---

Cell values are as follows:

- (m,n)=1 if condition and symptom are associated
- (m,n)=2 if condition and symptom CANNOT be associated. The presence of this symptom excludes the condition as a possible diagnosis.
- (m,n)=null if no information exists or if symptom and condition are not associated

I'm struggling to write an SQL query which will identify all the columns (n) for a specific condition (m) where the value of the cell (m,n) = 2.

So far my reading has highlighted ideas about pivot tables (I can't see how I would be able to use them for this problem) and database normalisation which I don't think is possible because of the other queries I am running on the same table.

An example based on the table above:

- Patient presents with hyporeflexia
- SQL query identifies this could be cause by either "abetalipoproteinaemia" or "vitamin B12 deficiency" - this all works fine already
- I want to establish whether any of the conditions identified (abetalipoproteinaemia and vitamin B12 deficiency) have symptoms that would exclude the diagnosis (any cell in that row = 2) and return the name of any column (symptom) for which this is the case.
- A query to the SQL database identifies vitamin B12 deficiency would be excluded as a possible diagnosis if spinothalamic hypoesthesia is present - this will be fed back to the html display.

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks for your time!

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. Which are you *really* using here? Nevermind, this is clearly MySQL, due to the use of backticks for quoting.

Comment: This query would be easier if the table representing the relationship between condition and symptom had three columns: symptom, condition, association type. It would also make it easier to add more symptoms. As it is now, you'll have to alter your table.

Comment: and to add to @Don'tPanic 's comment not to mention you would have to convert the columns into records (unpivotting) to make the query more easy as you want to query and filter based on conditions..

Comment: Problems like this are sometimes symptomatic of poor or inappropriate design

Comment: 'and database normalisation which I don't think is possible because of the other queries I am running on the same table' - this is highly unlikely to be a) true or b) adequate justification if it were. However, if you really couldn't amend the design then you would be best off not using an RDBMS in the first place.

Comment: @Strawberry with more experience now I understand your point and have proceeded using an RDBMS with normalised databases. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be more usual to arrange the data something like this - apologies for any spelling errors or poor terminology, but if you pay peanuts...

```
syptom                 condition                   exclusion
Abetalipoproteinaemia  Diarrhoea                           0
Abetalipoproteinaemia  Hyporeflexia                        0
Caffeine toxicity      Diarrhoea                           0
Caffeine toxicity      Headache                            0
Vitamin B12 deficiency Hyporeflexia                        0    
Vitamin B12 deficiency Hypoaesthesia Spinthalamic          1
```

You would then take this one or two steps further, and have a table for symptoms, a table for conditions, and a table which says which symptom relates to which condition, and how.

Comment: Thank you! I think this has been the best way forward - sorry poor initial database design on my behalf!

Answer (score 1):

Query pattern would be much more straightforward if the table were designed following normative relational patterns.

Consider the resultset returned by a query of this form:

```
SELECT v.condition
     , v.symptom
     , v.associated_or_excluded
  FROM ( SELECT t1.`Condition`  AS `condition`
              , 'Diarrhoea'     AS `symptom`
              , t1.`Diarrhoea`  AS `associated_or_excluded`
           FROM mytable t1
          UNION ALL
         SELECT t2.`Condition`
              , 'Headache'
              , t2.`Headache`
           FROM mytable t2
          UNION ALL
         SELECT t3.`Condition`
              , 'Hyporeflexia'
              , t3.`Hyporeflexia`
           FROM mytable t3
          UNION ALL
         SELECT t4.`Condition`
              , 'Hypoaesthesia_Spinothalamic'
              , t4.`Hypoaesthesia_Spinothalamic`
           FROM mytable t4
       ) v
```

We could use that query as an inline view (a rowsource) for an outer query, or a new table could be populated with the result from this query `INSERT ... SELECT` to convert.

---

With that resultset, with the data in standard relational form, we avoid the struggle by writing a simple query like this:

```
SELECT t.symptom
  FROM ( ... ) t
 WHERE t.condition              = 'Hyporeflexia'
   AND t.associated_or_excluded = 2
```

that will return symptoms that are excluded from a particular condition.

(or, to put it in terms of the original question, where a value of 2 is found the intersection of *m* and *n*)

Note that `( ... )` is replaced with a table name or with an inline view returning the result from query above.

Note that the entirety of the "struggle" is inside the parens, with the inline view query that gets the data represented in a suitable form.

```
SELECT t.symptom
  FROM ( -- inline view query 

         SELECT t1.`Condition`  AS `condition`
              , 'Diarrhoea'     AS `symptom`
              , t1.`Diarrhoea`  AS `associated_or_excluded`
           FROM mytable t1
          UNION ALL
         SELECT t2.`Condition`
              , 'Headache'
              , t2.`Headache`
           FROM mytable t2
          UNION ALL
         SELECT t3.`Condition`
              , 'Hyporeflexia'
              , t3.`Hyporeflexia`
           FROM mytable t3
          UNION ALL
         SELECT t4.`Condition`
              , 'Hypoaesthesia_Spinothalamic'
              , t4.`Hypoaesthesia_Spinothalamic`
           FROM mytable t4

      ) t
WHERE t.condition              = 'Hyporeflexia'
  AND t.associated_or_excluded = 2
```

Comment: Thank your for your assistance! While your answer has been extremely useful as you and several others have suggested the best approach here was to restructure the database to be normative. While this approach would have been scalable to a large database I think it would have made things unneccesarily complicated - poor database design on my behalf sorry!